# Using include <string> and using namespace std; but string still breaks my program

Tags: c++, string, eclipse-cdt

I'm following a tutorial for beginner C++ (https://www.udemy.com/course/free-learn-c-tutorial-beginners/learn/lecture/1368442#overview) and they very neatly wrote `string text1 = "Hello"` and then printed it. I tried this, then again with `#include <string>` and I'm still getting an error in the console. My code is here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int numberCats = 5; // creates an int variable numberCats with value 5
    int numberDogs = 1;

    cout << "I have " << numberCats << " cats and " << numberDogs << " dogs." << endl; // prints
    cout << "In total I have " << numberCats+numberDogs << " pets." << endl;

    numberDogs += 1; // update variable

    cout << "I just bought a dog. Now I have " << numberDogs << "." << endl;

    string text1 = "Hello!" ; // creates a string variable (class)

    cout << text1 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And I get this message at the top of my console, and no output:

`<terminated> (exit value: -1,073,741,511) udemy_course.exe [C/C++ Application] ...`

If I remove the string line and the cout line underneath it, the program runs fine with this message at the top of the console:

`<terminated> (exit value: 0) udemy_course.exe [C/C++ Application] ...`

And the output:

```
I have 5 cats and 1 dogs.
In total I have 6 pets.
I just bought a dog. Now I have 2.
```

I feel like this should be REALLY easy, and can't figure out why it's not working at all. Everything I've looked up says to put #include  and/or using namespace std; or change every string to std::string. None of this helps.

I'm using eclipse and minGW, pretty much exactly the same as the udemy course I'm following (except Windows, not Mac). Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think the problem  / bug is in the udemy console and not your code.

Comment: The given code works just fine ([Your example in Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/eGTW4KTne))

Comment: General advice, when learning it's best to learn what functions and methods are in each namespace, so using ``std::cout`` rather than ``using namespace std;``

Comment: [Code works fine here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1f9099073c13ea8c)

Comment: *Using directive* **bad**: `using namespace std;`.  *Using declaration* **okay**: `using std::cout;`

Comment: I remember seeing somewhere, that changing the Tool Chain Editor helps (I have no idea what it is, just that I've seen it). Just changed toolchain and it's worked. Thanks for letting me know the code wasn't the problem!
Also @Eljay, I'm sure I'll get to that! I've only just started xD

Comment: Your code works. It's fine. You should stop using `using namespace std;` at the global scope. At least move it to block scope (eg: the main function)

Comment: Yes I've heard this a fair bit! I've just started C++, coming over from Python. Is this namespace thing similar to Python's `from module import *`, where you just get all the functions in the module which can cause conflict. Rather, using `import module as mdl` then using mdl.function() is better? Is it the same as that?